# ActiveMQ monitor

Tags: activemq-classic, monitor

When using ActiveMQ, some problems troubles me:
1. When broker crashed or stopped, messages from sender will be lost(I set timeout, because the sender have others to do).
2. Consumer receives all messages from broker, but how i know the consumer received all messages(zero lost).
 
3. If message is lost, i want to know it immediately.

In production, I want to monitor the activemq, and know which message is lost.
Can anyone give me a favor?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a listener that is called as soon as you producers/consumers lose contact with broker.

http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.5.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener.html

If consumer crashes
use explicit ack: activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-transactions.html

you can use persistent messages to avoid losing messages if broker crashes:
activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html

Comment: Thanks. How do you do about monitor in production?

Comment: Assuming i am using persistent messages, messages should be stored inside the brokers persistence adapter until the consumer receives and acknowledges the message. But i used 'useAsyncSend' and 'soTimeout', in the case, losing messages occurs very frequently.